# Binary search using recursion, iteration, shifted array

Tags: c#, interview-questions, binary-search

Interview  question some engineer, asked me to write binary search in 2 ways,
Also asked me to write binary search on a shifted array (10 20 1 2 3 4).
Wrote that and then asked me to find the offset of the array in log n.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class BinarySearch
    {
        public BinarySearch()
        {
            int[] array = new int[10] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30 };
            int numberToFind = 10;
            int index = FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind, array, 0, array.Length - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("the number " + numberToFind + "is located at index: " + index);
            index = FindIndexIterative(numberToFind, array, 0, array.Length - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("the number " + numberToFind + "is located at index: " + index);
            int[] shiftedArray = new int[6]{10, 20, 1, 2, 3 ,4};

            index = FindShiftedArray(numberToFind, shiftedArray, 0, array.Length - 1);
        }

        private int FindShiftedArray(int numberToFind, int[] shiftedArray, int indexMin, int indexMax)
        {
            //we find the pivot and from there do a binary search
            int pivot = FindPivot(shiftedArray, 0, shiftedArray.Length - 1);
            //the pivot acts like the first slicing of the arrays
            if (shiftedArray[pivot] == numberToFind)
                return pivot;
            if (shiftedArray[0] <= numberToFind)
            {
                return FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind,shiftedArray, 0, pivot - 1 );
            }
            else
            {
                return FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind,shiftedArray, pivot + 1, shiftedArray.Length - 1 );
            }
        }

        private int FindPivot(int[] array, int indexMin, int indexMax)
        {

            if (indexMax < indexMin)  
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (indexMax == indexMin)
            {
                return indexMin;
            }
            int mid = (indexMin + indexMax)/2;   /*low + (high - low)/2;*/
            if (mid < indexMax && array[mid] > array[mid + 1])
            {
                return mid;
            }
            if (mid > indexMin && array[mid] < array[mid - 1])
            {
                return (mid-1);
            }
            if (array[indexMin] >= array[mid])
            {
                return FindPivot(array, indexMin, mid-1);
            }
            else
            {
                return FindPivot(array, mid + 1, indexMax);
            }
}

        public int FindIndexRecursive(int numberToFind, int[] array, int indexMin, int indexMax)
        {
            if (indexMin > indexMax)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            int mid = ((indexMax - indexMin) / 2 ) + indexMin;

            if (array[mid] < numberToFind)
            {                
               return FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind, array, mid, indexMax); 
            }
            else if (numberToFind < array[mid])
            {
                return FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind, array, indexMin, mid);
            }
            else 
            {
                return mid;
            }
        }

        public int FindIndexIterative(int numberToFind, int[] array, int indexMin, int indexMax)
        {
            while (indexMin < indexMax)
            {
                int mid = ((indexMax - indexMin) / 2) + indexMin;
                if (array[mid] < numberToFind)
                {
                    indexMin = mid;
                }
                else if (numberToFind < array[mid])
                {
                    indexMax = mid;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return mid;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `numberToFind > array[mid]` then the lower bound should be set to `mid + 1` as the value at `array[mid]` does not match. In the opposite case the upper bound should be set to `mid - 1`. If you don't do so, you might get stuck in an endless recursion. Say you are looking for 12 (at index 6) and you have `indexMin = 5` and `indexMax = 6`. `mid` becomes `5`. Now calling

```
FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind, array, mid, indexMax);
```

gives the same indexes again and `array[mid]` will never be 12!

I am also irritated by the test `array[mid] < numberToFind`. It seems more natural to me to perform the equivalent test `numberToFind > array[mid]`:

```
if (numberToFind > array[mid])
{
   return FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind, array, mid + 1, indexMax);
}
else if (numberToFind < array[mid])
{
    return FindIndexRecursive(numberToFind, array, indexMin, mid - 1);
}
else 
{
    return mid;
}
```

`mid` can be found more easily with:

```
int mid = (indexMin + indexMax) / 2;
```

Comment: The last statement could cause an integer overflow for big enough `indexMin` and `indexMax`. OP's approach is safe.

Comment: Good point. The limit, however, is at 2^31/2 = 1.07 billion items; high engough for most applications.